# Getting error while adding standard process template (enabling feature) to the TFS 2015 projects

Tags: tfs-2015

Am getting following error while adding standard process templates.
FYI, we upgraded to TFS 2015 from TFS 2013. This projects have customized workitems in TFS 2013.

**TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature. This feature cannot be used until you correct the configuration.
Learn about how to correct your configuration
Details about the validation error appear below:
The following element contains an error: PortfolioBacklog(Microsoft.FeatureCategory). TF400522: The following value is not a valid work item category: Microsoft.FeatureCategory. You must specify a valid category.
The following element contains an error: RequirementBacklog. TF400522: The following value is not a valid work item category: Microsoft.FeatureCategory. You must specify a valid category.
The following element contains an error: TaskBacklog. TF400522: The following value is not a valid work item category: Microsoft.TaskCategory. You must specify a valid category.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you customize your work items in TFS 2013?

Answer (score 1):

If you just add custom WITs and change the form layout. The [Configure Features Wizard](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade) will update your team projects and you’ll get access to the latest features.

If you change the workflow or renaming a WIT,then it might require you to perform some manual operations when updating your team project.

More information, see [Maintenance and upgrade implications (TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/customize-work#maintenance-and-upgrade-implications-tfs).